# A quick way to find files or directories given user and path when there are many users and files/directories

Tags: algorithm

This is an interview question. If you have millions of users and files/directories, how do you plan a good way to find files or directories given user and path?  If files/directories have time stamps, how do you count the number of files/directories added per day for each user? you can use your way to insert files/directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can store them in a database table (fields user, file, date) and make a simple query on them. DBMSs do the indexing to make it fast. If you don't want to use a DBMS such as [mysql](http://mysql.com) or [MS Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/), [SQL server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/default.aspx) or Oracle, you can use some open source search applications such as [Lemur](http://www.lemurproject.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a data base then you can use a combination of a `Dictionary` and a `Binary Search Tree`.

The `key` to the `Dictionary` will be the `user`.
The `value` of it with 2 properties:

1. A `Dictionary` with `day`s as `keys` and `number of entries that day` as `values`.
2. A `Binary Search Tree` with `path`s of the different files and folders as `nodes`.

Let `n` be the total number of the different files and folders.
It is built in `O(nlgn)` and the required operations are done in `O(lgn)`.

Comment: Can you be a little detail about a set with different dates?

Comment: Can you be a little detail about a set with different dates?  do you mean to create a linked list (node of the list has date, number of files/directories).

Comment: A Set is like a dictionary without values-only distinct keys. About the dates- If there are n entries at day 3/11/2012 it will be entered n times to the set but will be represented as one element, which is  3/11/2012. The file or folder will have the full date, like 3/11/2012 15:12:14, but the Set will hold only the different days.

Comment: Thanks, but based on your descriptions, a Set is a dictionary. It has key and value In this particular example, the key is date (3/11/2012), and the value has just one, the number_of_files_folders. Right?